# Compilation error with instanceof and generics

Tags: java, generics, java-8

```
public class A {
    public interface I<T> {
        public Integer toInt(T x);
    }
    public static int t(String s, I<String> i) {
        // System.out.println(i instanceof I<Integer>);
        return i.toInt(s);
    }
    public static <S> int g(S s, I<T> i){
        return i.toInt(s);
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println(t("dcba", s->(int)(s.charAt(0)+'a')));
    }
}
```

Why does the method `g` fail to pass compilation? Why does the line `System.out.println(i instanceof I<Integer>)` in the method `t` fail to pass compilation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`g` cannot use the generic type parameter `T` in its signature, since that parameter is only declared for the interface `I`.

You should probably change its signature to :

```
public static <S> int g(S s, I<S> i)
```

`i instanceof I<Integer>` doesn't pass compilation since generic type information is erased during compilation, so it's not available in runtime.

This is exactly what the compiler tells you :

> Cannot perform instanceof check against parameterized type `A.I<Integer>`. Use the form `A.I<?>` instead since further generic type information will be erased at runtime

Comment: "g cannot use the generic type parameter T in its signature"  so can it be a parameter "K"? Why did you choose "s"?

Comment: @shosh You chose `S`. You declared a generic type parameter `<S>` for the static method `g`, and it seems to make sense to use `S` for both the `s` parameter and the `i` parameter, since you pass `s` to `i.toInt()`.

Comment: Another option: `public static <S,T> int g(S s, I<T> i)`. Not tested, at probably won’t work with your message body.

Comment: @OleV.V. No it won't work, since the `toInt` method of `I<T>` expects a `T` parameter, not an `S` parameter.

Comment: About the interface: "public Integer toInt(T x)" why "Integer" instead of "int"  like it was written "public static int t(String s, I<String> i)"?

Comment: @shosh Both would work, since Integer can be auto-unboxed to int. That is, unless `Integer toInt(T x)` may return null, in which case the `t` and `g` methods would throw a `NullPointerException`.